# swagger codegen how to create .json

Tags: java, json, maven, swagger-codegen

I recently joined a team that are creating RESTful API. I'm a beginner to this field. My task is to create the SDK of the project. I have to use swagger-codegen for it. I am following instructions in [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)

There they are using **http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json** file to build the sdk. But in my project there is no .json file available. When i build the project using **mvn clean package** all i get is **.war** files.

So what i want to know is, do i need to create .json file to build a SDK, if so how do i build it? or can i do it in any other way?

sorry for my lack of knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to document your REST API in [OpenAPI/Swagger spec 2.0](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) (yaml/json file) to begin with.

You can also use plug-ins like [C# Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to automatically generate OpenAPI/Swagger spec from your RESTful backend.

After you obtain the spec (yaml/json file), then you can use [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) (free, open source) to generate API clients, server stubs and API documentations.

FYI. OpenAPI 3.0 (RC) can be found in https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/3.0.0-rc0/versions/3.0.md